# Docker pull rate request limit from Kubernetes environment

Tags: kubernetes

I logged in using docker login command in my machine.

then I tried to run the `kubectl` command to apply a `yaml` file:

`kubectl apply -f manifests/1_helloworld_deploy.yaml`

but this failed with error :

> Warning  Failed     20s (x2 over 35s)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "nginx:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/library/nginx:latest": failed to copy: httpReaderSeeker: failed open: unexpected status code https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/nginx/manifests/sha256:89ea560b277f54022cf0b2e718d83a9377095333f8890e31835f615922071ddc: 429 Too Many Requests - Server message: toomanyrequests: You have reached your pull rate limit. You may increase the limit by authenticating and upgrading: https://www.docker.com/increase-rate-limit

Now, I already logged in using the docker username and account, still I'm getting a pull rate error.

What should I do to make this working for `.yaml` file also?

Answer (score 1):

- When you login to docker on a machine , its credentials will be saved in a file named `~/.docker/config.json`
- We need need to explicitly instruct these credentials to be used while pulling images .
- For that we need to create a secret with contents of `~/.docker/config.json` and mention that as `imagePullSecrets` in the yaml file.

Following is a sample procedure :

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry my-secret --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=/root/.docker/config.json

In the podspec update it as image pull secret as following :

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: boo
spec:
  containers:
    - name: boo
      image: busybox
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: my-secret
```

[Detailed Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)